# How to specify 2D histogram image size and scale in pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I wish to produce a series of 2D histograms using pyplot. 
I want to be able to specify the size and scale (or aspect ratio) of the generated image. In addition to this, I would like to remove the ticks and axes labels and borders.

This does not seem to be possible in the arguments to the plt.hist2d() method.

Rather than share my (rather complex) code, I post the pyplot demo script. If what I want is possible with this code, then it will be possible with mine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000) + 5

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to create images (`.png` files or whatever) that contain *only* the histogram without any matplotlib axes annotations and padding. Is that correct?

Comment: @kazemakase, that is correct. But in particular, the aspect ratio needs to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the aspect alone will not help, you need the figure size in width or height in addition.
To get rid of the margins you can use `subplots_adjust`. And in order to turn the axes off you need `axis("off")`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000) + 5

width=4 # inch
aspect=0.8 # height/width ratio
height = width*aspect
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height ))
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, top=1, left=0, right=1)
plt.gca().axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest thank you, very helpful. Not sure why I had such trouble getting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The figsize should do what you want:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))    
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this does not appear to work for 2D histograms. Could you explain how this works in the above example?

Comment: @IanDella-Rocca edited my answer to combine it with your comment. Juste change the `(20,10)` tuple to the ratio you want for your figure.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet shows how to quickly and easily

- set the figure size (and implicitly the aspect ratio)
- disable the axis bounding box and tick annotations
- set the axis to fill the whole figure (removes borders)
- save the resulting figure to an image file.

.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000) + 5

plt.figure(figsize=[7, 2])  # set figure dimensions to weird but illustrative aspect ratio
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40)
plt.box(False)  # disable axis box
plt.xticks([])  # no x axis ticks
plt.yticks([])  # no y axis ticks
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)  # remove borders
plt.savefig('output.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like I have been beaten to the answer by a few minutes but `axis("off")` is actually neater than `box`/`xticks`/`yticks`.